# Is it possible to generate Enterprise/In house Provisioning Profile of a wildcard AppID?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, in-house-distribution

I am trying to generate a Enterprise provisioning profile from an wildcard AppID but I am required to set a explicit AppID to generate the provisioning profile.
One mobileprovision with a wildcard appID would be enough for our users to install our different applications and they are not forced to install a mobileprovision for each .ipa we develop.
I am pretty sure this was possible in the past (around 2014)

How could achieve this?

**Edit (Some more information added)**

- I am able to create wildcard appIDs and with those appIDs I can generate development or ad-hoc provision profiles but not In House provision profiles.
- When creating In House Development profiles from the website just explicit App Ids are shown.
- When trying export In House apps with AppIDs that are not already defined in the web this message appears:
  [image: WILDCARD APP IDs can not be used to create In House provisioning profiles. Please use an Explicit App ID]
- I this [Apple Developer link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html) It can be read in the 4th step "You can not distribute an enterprise app using a wildcard App ID"
- I am using Xcode 6.1.1 and the In House account is pretty new

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same story here : on a "recent" iOS entreprise account (i.e. late 2014 or start 2015), the wildcard appID is not proposed when creating an in-house distribution profile.

Just tested with an older account: the wildcard appID is  listed when I want to create a new in-house distribution profile.

Comment: Just curious, because this answer is a bit vague.  Is the wildcard not proposed? Or is it not allowed?  My account is older, so I can still use the wildcard app ID.  Also, is it that you cannot create the wildcard app ID in the developer portal, or can you not select it when creating the enterprise distribution profile.  Thanks for updating the anwser to clarify things!

Comment: On the old account, the wildcard is still proposed at profile creation. But recently, I had problem with such app: the app generate error at installation such as "the provisioning profile has expired". That was not the case, it was still valid for a few months. So, I think in-house app distributed with wildcard appID are no more accepted by recent iOS system (iOS 9 tested). The same app with a dedicated appId installed without problem.

Comment: Well, it must be something else, because we are still using an enterprise app distribution profile with a wildcard ID and have no problems with iOS 9 (or any other iOS version).  I'm stiull curious why some are seeing problems where we are not.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can certainly create an enterprise in house provisioning profile that uses the wildcard app id.  We do it today, and I just tried creating a new one and it let me.  You cannot use wildcard app IDs if your app needs to do iCloud, Game Center, In-App Purchases, etc., but for standard apps you should be fine.  If you cannot, there may be another issue.  Post more details about how you are required to set and explicit app ID and maybe we can be more help.

Do you have an existing iOS Wildcard AppID when you go to the App IDs section on the developer site?

Comment: I have added some more information in the question. Yep I have IOS Wildcard AppId when you go to the AppIDs section of the developer site. thanks

Comment: That's odd.  I'm not sure if maybe we were grandfathered in because we've been using this for a while.  We do all our management of the profiles through the web site, but it sounds like you tried to manually create the profile on the developer site and it does not list the app ID.

Comment: Also, the Apple documentation seems to contradict itself: "If necessary, Xcode creates a distribution certificate, provisioning profile, and explicit App ID for you. (You can not distribute an enterprise app using a wildcard App ID.) The name of the distribution provisioning profile begins with the text XC: followed by the App ID. If you are using a wildcard App ID, the name of the distribution provisioning profile is XC:*."