# iOS Enterprise Build - Cannot use wild card

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

[image]

I get the above error when I try to export an enterprise build. I do not have Wildcard App Id. However it Xcode creates one while I prepare the archive.

I am using Xcode 7.2.

I re-created all the certificates and profiles to handle it, but that did not work. Any ideas what is causing this issue and how I can get over it?

Comment: You are using provision profile which interact with your wildcard charcter identifer like com.xxx.* make sure remake provision profile with your app explict id like com.xxxx.yourappname

Comment: There is no provisioning profile with wildcard characters.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311152/is-it-possible-to-generate-enterprise-in-house-provisioning-profile-of-a-wildcar

Comment: @Muhammad , it is about using wildcard, I am not using wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it is bug in Xcode 7.2 ,  after trying multiple times and troubleshooting , below solution worked for me.

1) Open Xcode preference

2) Select the team

3) Click the "View Details.."

4) In section "Provisioning Profiles": Right Click on any profile and Show in Finder and Delete All Provisioning Profiles in that folder.

5) In section "Provisioning Profiles". Click on "Download All".

6) Restart the Xcode.

7) Select Team in General, and Provisioning Profiles in Build Settings and archive build again.

For more detail find Screenshots below:

**1) Open Xcode preference,**

[image]

**2) Select the team,**
[image]

**3) Click the "View Details..".**

**4) In section "Provisioning Profiles": Right Click on any profile and Show in Finder and Delete All Provisioning Profiles in that folder.**

[image]

**Delete Provisioning Profiles**
[image]

**5) In section "Provisioning Profiles". Click on "Download All".**

[image]

**6) Restart the Xcode.** (most of the times Restarting Xcode is only solution after downloading new provisioning profiles or after changing App identifiers)

**7) Select Team in General, and Provisioning Profiles in Build Settings and archive build again.**

Hope it solves your problem. :)

P.S: I've also opened a bug to Apple via Apple Bug Reporter.

Comment: Yes It indeed does help. Thanks Muhammad.

Comment: Any response from Apple re: the bug? I'm having the same issue, but the steps above aren't resolving it for me. Definitely using an explicit appId.

Comment: @StephShelley repeat above step and restart your system also.